# Can LL4148 replace 1N4001?

Tags: protection

The circuit takes **5V** and will not consume more than **250mA**. I have to use a reverse polarity protection diode, usually I use a *1N4001*, but now I'm designing a PCB with all SMD components.

I have an *LL4148* available. With this information, can someone tell me if it is safe to use *LL4148* as a reverse polarity diode for a 1.25W circuit?

Comment: Do you realize, that your reverse polarity diode "eats" 1V? Maybe use shottky diode instead?

Comment: If your circuit uses regulated 5V, then it's better to use a MOSFET in series to protect against reverse polarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a definitive answer you should consult the datasheet of your manufacturer, but the first one I googled has this graph

[image]

The maximum average current is 200 mA, but only if you can keep the ambient temperature under 25 C.

BTW the power used by your circuit is irrelevant, only the current counts. And in this case I would not use an 4148, at least not when I am the person that gets the problem when the circuit fails.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer - no,

because LL4148 diode is rated at 200mA (forward average current maximum rating).

At 250mA diode will be overloaded by 25%.

I think maximum continuous/average current is dictated by heat disspation.

If you are desperate - you may use much bigger soldering pads for that diode to take out and radiate that extra 50mW of heat.

You may use 2 LL4148 diodes in parallel which is other desperate way (not recommended).

Personally - Im using small shottky diodes for reverse polarity protection. They have very small voltage drop (0.3V for example), so they produce much less heat and waste less energy.

Comment: Paralleling diodes without anything to get good current sharing is a bad idea.

Comment: In this case there is no need for good (balanced) current sharing.

Comment: Yes there is, else you don't get the benefit of multiple diodes.  If one diode takes all the current, you are effectively back to having a single diode.  It is much better to use the appropriately sized diode in the first place.  Fortunately there are many diodes that can handle 5 V and 250 mA.  As you say, a Schottky would be a good fit here.

Comment: But I can't imagine situation when one diode takes all current. I think it's not possible. Kirhoff! :) However connecting diodes in parallel without resistors is wrong. It's wrong and bad idea, but it will work :)